# setRequestedOrientation, but still change according to sensor

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, android-sensors

I would like to simulate youtube video-view behaviour in terms of handling screen orientation.

use cases:
**p1**. when user press maximise -> activity always goes into landscape 
**p2**. when user press minimise -> activity always goes into portrait
**p3**. when user rotates the device -> screen orientation should change accordingly even if **p1** or **p2** was applied before.

Currently I use:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
     } else {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
     }
```

However this locks the orientation permanently and fails **p3**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After playing around for a while I have found the right solution. 
First of all - the problem is that android locks the screen after setRequestedOrientation call, you can't have a mix of both, the only to do it is to do everything manually.

Here is how:

```
class PlayerOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {
    PlayerOrientationListener() {
        super(VideoPlayerActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        int threshold = 5;
        if (Math.abs(orientation - 0) < threshold) orientation = 0;
        else if (Math.abs(orientation - 90) < threshold) orientation = 90;
        else if (Math.abs(orientation - 180) < threshold) orientation = 180;
        else if (Math.abs(orientation - 270) < threshold) orientation = 270;

        switch (orientation) {
            case 0:
                if (!orientationLandscapeLocked) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    orientationPortraitLocked = false;
                }
                break;
            case 90:
                if (!orientationPortraitLocked) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                    orientationLandscapeLocked = false;
                }
                break;
            case 180:
                if (!orientationLandscapeLocked) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                    orientationPortraitLocked = false;
                }
                break;
            case 270:
                if (!orientationPortraitLocked) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    orientationLandscapeLocked = false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and activity code:

```
View.OnClickListener onExpandClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
                orientationLandscapeLocked = true;
                orientationPortraitLocked = false;
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
                orientationPortraitLocked = true;
                orientationLandscapeLocked = false;
            }
        }
    };
btnExpandVideo.setOnClickListener(onExpandClick);

orientationListener = new PlayerOrientationListener();
orientationListener.enable();
```

Comment: I can not extend OrientationEventListener as i am already extending my class with drawer activity. Is there anyother solution?

Comment: This and the kotlin implementation work great, just as I needed it. However, I would add a way to avoid Memory Leaks by releasing the View reference inside the OrientationListener subclass. Either by allowing a well-managed weak reference or a direct release() method that needs to be called from onDestroy(). Thank you for the implementation.

Answer (score 9):

@Yuriy's answer worked great for me, here it is in Kotlin with some minor modifications so that it can live in a separate file:

```
class PlayerOrientationListener(val activity: Activity?) : OrientationEventListener(activity) {
    companion object {
        private const val ROT_THRESHOLD = 5

        private const val ROT_0 = 0
        private const val ROT_90 = 90
        private const val ROT_180 = 180
        private const val ROT_270 = 270
    }

    private var orientationLockedPortrait = false
    private var orientationLockedLandscape = false

    fun lockLandscape() {
        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
        orientationLockedLandscape = true
        orientationLockedPortrait = false
    }

    fun lockPortrait() {
        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
        orientationLockedPortrait = true
        orientationLockedLandscape = false
    }

    override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
        if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
            return
        }

        val rotation: Int =
                when {
                    Math.abs(orientation - ROT_0) < ROT_THRESHOLD -> ROT_0
                    Math.abs(orientation - ROT_90) < ROT_THRESHOLD -> ROT_90
                    Math.abs(orientation - ROT_180) < ROT_THRESHOLD -> ROT_180
                    Math.abs(orientation - ROT_270) < ROT_THRESHOLD -> ROT_270
                    else -> ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN
                }

        when (rotation) {
            ROT_0 -> if (!orientationLockedLandscape) {
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                orientationLockedPortrait = false
            }
            ROT_90 -> if (!orientationLockedPortrait) {
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
                orientationLockedLandscape = false
            }
            ROT_180 -> if (!orientationLockedLandscape) {
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
                orientationLockedPortrait = false
            }
            ROT_270 -> if (!orientationLockedPortrait) {
                activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
                orientationLockedLandscape = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Fragment, something like:

```
val orientationListener = PlayerOrientationListener(activity)
orientationListener.enable()

menuItemMaximize?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    orientationListener.lockLandscape()
    true
}

menuItemMinimize?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    orientationListener.lockPortrait()
    true
}
```